# Angular ui-router resolve http empty value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm testing a simple angular application and I'm facing some problems. The http GET call is done but resolver renders empty. Here is the code :

A simple index.html :

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <head>
  //all scripts loaded
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="myCtrl">  
  <p>{{test}}</p>
  <a ui-sref="tab1">Show Tab 1</a>
  <a ui-sref="tab2">Show Tab 2</a>
  <a ui-sref="tab3">Show Tab 3</a>

  <ui-view></ui-view>
 </body>
</html>
```

The app.js :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

app
.service('DataService', function ($http) { 
    return {
        getData: function() {
            return $http({
                method : "GET",
                url : "/hi"
            }).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            },function(response) {
                return "error";
            });
        }
    }
});

app
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = "Test";
});

app
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('tab1', {
        url: '/tab1',
        templateUrl: '/assets/templates/tab1.html'
    })
    .state('tab2', {
        url: '/tab2',
        templateUrl: '/assets/templates/tab2.html'
    })
    .state('tab3', {
        url: '/tab3',
        templateUrl: '/assets/templates/tab3.html'
        resolve:{
            mydata : function (DataService) {
                return DataService.getData();
            }
        },
        controller: 'myCtrl'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab1');
});
```

Tab3 template :

```
<p>Data: {{mydata}}</p>
```

As I said, when I click the "tab3" link, the http get call is done, and a JSON data is retrieved, but "mydata" is rendered to blank.

Any clue??
Thanks and regards.

Comment: try to open `chrome inspector -> network panel` and see what your web service returns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller doesn't do anything with mydata. So it's not in the scope, so the view can't display it. It should be:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, mydata) {
  $scope.mydata = mydata;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, anyway I tried that before but the controller can not find "mydata". Just throws an error. How can I inject "mydata" to the controller?

Comment: That's because you're using myCtrl for your main, index.html page, although it's supposed to tbe the controller of the tab3 route, requiring mydata. Remove `ng-controller="myCtrl"` from index.html.